# How to get Play! Framework to serve a XML response

Tags: xml, playframework, playframework-2.0

Somehow I can't figure out how to get Play! to serve an XML response. And I don't understand the documentation either (which you can find [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaXmlRequests)).

My goal is to create a sitemap, so the response should be a `Content-Type: application/xml;`

How would you alter the following controller to serve that Content-Type?

```
public static Result sitemap() {
    return ok("<message \"status\"=\"OK\">Hello Paul</message>");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `@BodyParser.Of(Xml.class)` annotation to your `sitemap`-method?

Comment: Yes, it still serves a "text/plain" :/

Comment: There are different ways... as tehlexx mentioned by using the @BodyParser Annotation (set correct mime type with `response().setContentType("application/xml")`) or even simpler: Use templates,like you do with HTML Pages. Thats probably the fastest method to generate some XML response.

Comment: Wow, awesome. This works. Thanks! But the @BodyParser Annotations isn't necessary, response().setContentType("application/xml") does the job. Thank you very much. Why don't you put your comment as an answer? So I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Play will set `Content-type` header properly if you will deliver it to `ok()` method in right way. For an example if you are returning the `String` (as you showed in question) it considers that's `text/plain`. You have at least 2 ways, the fastest (but ugly) is forcing content type, Jürgen suggest setting it to response, but de facto Play has a shortcut:

```
public static Result sitemap() {
    return ok("<message status=\"OK\">Hello Paul</message>").as("text/xml");
}
```

On the other hand probably using XML template is better and cleaner option than building it with *glued* strings... Just create the XML file:

`/app/views/sitemap.scala.xml`:

```
<message status="OK">John Doe</message>
```

So you can use it as easy as:

```
public static Result index() {
    return ok(views.xml.sitemap.render());
}
```

Of course this file is common Play's template, so you can pass data to it and process inside (ie. iterate list of items, etc)

Comment: Is the content-type set automatically with the xml template? Not sure as it is not the case for json.

Comment: Yes it is set automatically, also if you'll use ie. `JsonNode` like:
`return ok(Json.toJson(someObj));` it will be set as a `application/json` etc.